# AttributeError: 'Pandas' object has no attribute 'AnnualIncome'

Tags: python, pandas

```
import mysql.connector




import pandas as pd

# Connect to MySQL




mydb = mysql.connector.connect(





    host='localhost',




    user='root',

   


 password='**********',

    database='Customer'
)

cursor = mydb.cursor()


# Read CSV file
data = pd.read_csv("Customers.csv")


# Insert data into MySQL
for row in data.itertuples():

   cursor.execute("""

    INSERT INTO Customer (Gender, Age, AnnualIncome, SpendingScore, Profession, WorkExperience, FamilySize)

    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)

    """, (row.Gender, row.Age, row.AnnualIncome, row.SpendingScore, row.Profession, 
row.WorkExperience, row.FamilySize))

# Commit changes and close connection

mydb.commit()

mydb.close()
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong I'm continuously getting this error message: AttributeError: 'Pandas' object has no attribute 'AnnualIncome'. These are the column names in the CVS file:CustomerID,Gender,Age,Annual Income ($),Spending Score (1-100),Profession,Work Experience,Family Size. And this is the sql table that I've created-

CREATE TABLE Customer.Customers(
CustomerID int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Gender ENUM('Male', 'Female'),
Age int,
AnnualIncome int,
SpendingScore int,
Profession VARCHAR(255),
WorkExperience int,
FamilySize int
);

Can anyone show me where I went wrong and why I'm getting this error message. Your response is greatly appreciated.

I'm expecting to see the data that is within the CVS file imported into the sql table that I've created on vscode.

Comment: You're accessing `row.AnnualIncome`, but `row` doesn't have a `AnnualIncome` attribute. Please fix your question, because the current formatting circus makes it next to unreadable.

Comment: *”the column names in the CVS file: [..]Annual Income ($)”* — Well, that’s not “AnnualIncome”, is it?